# SQL Update instruction won't pass parameters in C#

Tags: c#, sql, parameters, sql-update

So im working in winforms and im using a class for my SQL instructions, the database is made in MSAcces.

Code in the form :

```
OleDbConnection TabellenCon = new OleDbConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.BibDatabaseCon);

TabellenCon.Open();
OleDbCommand AuteurUpdaten = new OleDbCommand(SQL_Scripts.SQL_AuteurOpslaan, TabellenCon);

AuteurUpdaten.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AuteurVoornaam", SelectieTable.Rows[i][1]);
AuteurUpdaten.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AuteurAchternaam", SelectieTable.Rows[i][2]);
AuteurUpdaten.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AuteurGeslacht", SelectieTable.Rows[i][3]);
AuteurUpdaten.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AuteursID", SelectieTable.Rows[i][0]);
AuteurUpdaten.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test", SelectieTable.Rows[i][4]);


AuteurUpdaten.ExecuteNonQuery();
TabellenCon.Close();
```

Code in the SQL class:

```
public static readonly string SQL_AuteurOpslaan = "UPDATE tblAuteur SET Voornaam = @AuteurVoornaam,Achternaam = @AuteurAchternaam,Geslacht = @AuteurGeslacht , test = @test WHERE AuteursID = @AuteursID;";
```

So the table has 5 columns: AuteursID, Voornaam, Achternaam, Geslacht,test (these names are in dutch so could be column1,column2,.. aswell).

Now for some reason this code is not working but when I would remove the last column in the SQL instruction 'test' then it does work. Im 100% the problem isn't with the column or with the database. I have the same problem with other UPDATE instructions, they work untill I hit 4 parameters, no errors either just nothing happens animore.

Any ideas?

Comment: in Access (OleDB) parameters aren't truly named parameters. You need to specify the parameters in the same order they appear in your sql statement. Try swapping `@AuteursID` and `@Test` in your parameter order. The way you have it is that whatever is in `SelectieTable.Rows[i][4]` is what you're specifying in your WHERE clause.

Comment: That worked, thank you Charles!